# for how long can we pause a Mongo DB atlas database and after how much time we can pause it again

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am making a website with m30 mongo DB atlas database I want to open it for only a few months and then close it for the rest of the year is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could but you'd be paying for storage even when the database is not running.

It would be more efficient to dump & restore if you know you wouldn't need the database for a long time.

Comment: I actually want to add entries only for a few months and for the rest of the year I want data to be fetched and viewed only. Can you tell me how to do it and what is the cost of storage?

Comment: When you pause and unpause there is a note shown in UI with the cost going forward.